Sudoku Validator returning incorrect boolean
I know people dont like homework questions however,i have been working on this too long now over 6 hours, and am out of ideas, and for some reason my sudoku validator keeps returning the wrong boolean, it has to be the sudokuisvalid part, but i have no clue why it wont return the correct boolean now
rewrote the code but unfortunately i dont know anyother way to go about that part, still nothing, i rechecked all the other parts, checked getRow, works perfectly, checked getColumn, works perfectly, checked getSection, works perfectly, checked includes1To9, also works perfectly its something in the sudokuIsValid part but I can not figure out what is wrong with it, it seems like it accesses getRow, getColumn, getSection, and the incudes1To9 fine, and it displays a boolean but only says true...
tried to do as something based off of what someone said here, it is still doing that true when supposed to be false thing.
Error: sudokuIsValid returns true for valid sample puzzle (the variable puzzle)
Error 2: sudokuIsValid returns true for other valid puzzles not provided in the problem
im really hoping its something obvious and im just too tired, and im new to programming so ill paste my code and see what y'all think!
I tried to make what i believe is the problem area in bold which just put asterisk around it
function getRow(puzzle, row) {
// WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
return puzzle[row]
}

function getColumn(puzzle, col) {
// WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
return puzzle.map(row=>row[col])
}

function getSection(puzzle, x, y) {
// WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
let section = []
for(i = 3 * y; i < 3 * y + 3; i++){
  for(j = 3 * x; j < 3*x+3 ; j++){
    section.push(puzzle[i][j])
  }
}
return section
}

function includes1To9(arr) {
// WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
      if (j != i){
        if (arr[i] === arr[j]){
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true
}

function sudokuIsValid(puzzle) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    if(includes1To9(getRow) === false){
      return false
    }
  }
  for (let i= 0; i < 9; i++){
    if(includes1To9(getColumn) === false){
      return false
    }
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(let j =0; j < 3; j++){
      if(includes1To9(getSection) === false){
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  return true
}

// example of the puzzle that is being input and returning true, should return false

let puzzleTwo = [[ 8,9,5,  7,4,2,  1,3,6 ],
                 [ 8,7,1,  9,6,3,  4,8,5 ],
                 [ 4,6,3,  5,8,1,  7,9,2 ],

                 [ 9,3,4,  6,1,7,  2,5,8 ],
                 [ 5,1,7,  2,3,8,  9,6,4 ],
                 [ 6,8,2,  4,5,9,  3,7,1 ],

                 [ 1,5,9,  8,7,4,  6,2,3 ],
                 [ 7,4,6,  3,2,5,  8,1,9 ],
                 [ 3,2,8,  1,9,6,  5,4,7 ]];

console.log(sudokuIsValid(puzzleTwo)) // returns true should be false
console.log(includes1To9([8,8,4,9,5,6,1,7,3])) // returns false like it should


If you check the console you'll see an error explaining that getrow doesn't exist. JS function names are case sensitive.

You have function code written bad in valid.push(getrow(puzzle,i)), it should be getRow()

Could you add an example of a puzzle where the error occurs?

just fixed the issue where there was a 1 where an i was supposed to be and the getrow issue but still not working right

Add logging and have a look at How do I ask and answer homework questions?.

You have also mistake in if(includes1To9(valid[i] === false)){return false}", because valid[i] === false returns a boolean value and function includes1To9 expects an array.

I also recommend using for-of or forEach loops instead of for loops, so the code is much more readable.

If you want, you can always search that on some IT websites (I recommend W3Schools). Does it work after fixing that issue I have mentioned before? :)

To add on what @RedApple was saying, for this particular instance it seems you should have if(include1to9(valid) === false) if your goal is to check the return value of include1to9 with the valid array as input. P.S. also you don't need a for loop to cycle through valid, since you already are doing it in the include1to9() function

Can you please post the complete error you're getting, if any, and maybe some tests you are trying?
Also, a code advise: since you are trying to return false if include1to9(valid) is false and true otherwise, you can omit the if-else statement altogether just by doing return include1to9(valid);

Please give us an example of the value you are logging

Homework questions are okay, as long as you ask a specific question and show your research and debugging effort. How to debug small programs StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.

"ive tried make an else to see if that fixed it but all i did was flop the problem" It's less interesting what you've randomly tried to solve the problem. It's more interesting, what you found out when you've stepped line by line with your debugger through the code. Which exact line had unexpected behavior (and I don't mean the return value of the function)?

Set a breakpoint at return includes1To9(valid) in your debugger and analyze valid. I think, that's one unexpected value. You don't need let valid = [] at all. You can immediately return false if one of the conditions isn't fulfilled.

There is a fundamental problem in getSection() and in how you treat valid in sudokuIsValid(): getSection() returns an array and you push it into valid that is an array containing already the values inside puzzle, since you are pushing before calling getSection() the functions getRow() and getColumn(). I suggest you to rethink what you are trying to do and maybe add a new function to better separate the check on the section and the column one

It works now, isnt it?

@CcmU i may have misunderstood what you were saying i tried to set the values of the row into a new variable and same with the column and section then put that into the valid variable but that also didn't work i'm gonna update my code so you can see the change, I probably did it terribly too

@RedApple sadly not

The first thing you should learn, is how to use a debugger. I teach it in week one or week two. If you don't know, what a debugger is, learn it before you continue your course. Programmers don't have to guess where the issues are. They don't have to find them with trial and error or with debug outputs. The can step through each line, each expression, analyze and manipulate the values. What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

IMO, if the course asks you for a sudoku validator before it taught you how to use a debugger, it's a horrible introduction course. I would look for another one.

How to improve your code and solve your problem:

You don't need to have a list of valid. You can check every possibility and if the function returns false then you can immediately return false. At the end of the function you can do return true. this will solve your problem since in your includes1to9 you check all the rows, columns and subgrids. that means you check if there are numbers through 1 to 9 in the entire puzzle and if you find two of the same items, then you exit. so for example if you have a sudoku puzzle like this:
900 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 009
it will return true cause (if we don't check zeros) there are two nines in the puzzle. 2 nines in two rows, 2 nines in two columns, 2 nines in two subgrids = 6 nines...

Note:  - use Sets (if you learned them). They cannot contain duplicate items, eg. if you have an array that is 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 (duplicate 2s), then it will give you 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. You can then compare the array to the set and see if they are similiar size. You can use your double-for loop. while it is fine, Sets will simplify your code. if you haven't learned about Sets or you don't understand them, then don't use them.


So from these, your code should look like this:

function SudokuIsValid(sudoku){
  for row {
    if (row is not valid){
      return false
      // return false exits/stops the function. 
      // No code after this will be run in this function.
    }
  }
  // if code has gotten here, that means that all rows are valid.
  for column {
    if (column is not valid){
      return false
    }
  }
  // if code has gotten here, that means all columns are valid
  for subgrid {
    if (subgrid is not valid){
      return false
    }
  }
  // if code has gotten here, that means all rows, columns and subgrids are valid.
  // we can return true then
  return true
}


@RipperReborn can you show me how did you try to do it? (code)

i updated the code on the post its where the old sudokuisvalid function is

@RipperReborn you pass a function to includes1to9. You need to call it. What you do is: includes1to9( getRow ). You should do includes1to9(  getRow(puzzle, row)  ). etc. for row, column, subgrid.

omg thank you so much, i have been at this for around 10 hours and it finally works!!,

As explained in the comments, there are some issue in how you approached the problem: as you wrote it, getSection() returns an array and you push it into valid which itself is an array containing already the values inside puzzle, since getRow() and getColumn() are pushed into it before pushing in getSection().
Here it is my approach following your code as a base, I strongly suggest you to take and see what are the differences between said approach and yours. You can take inspiration from this code to try recreate your own as an exercise.
function getRow(puzzle, row)  {return puzzle[row]};
function getColumn(puzzle, col) {return puzzle.map(row => row[col])};

function getSection(puzzle, x, y) {
  // Initializing the section matrix
  let section = [[],[],[]];
  for(i = 3 * x; i < 3 * x + 3; i++){
    for(j = 3 * y; j < 3*y+3 ; j++){
      // Pushing into the matrix 3x3 each element (0 % 3 == 0, 3 % 0 == 0, etc...)
      section[i%3].push(puzzle[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return section;
};

function arrayIncludes1To9(arr) {
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++)  {
    // If i is not in the array return false
    if (!arr.includes(i))  {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // True otherwise
  return true;
}
function sectionIncludes1To9(matr)  {
  let arr = [];
  // Getting each matrix as an array to reutilize arrayIncludes1To9()
  matr.forEach(element => {
    element.map(x => arr.push(x));
  });
  return arrayIncludes1To9(arr);
}

function sudokuIsValid(puzzle) {
  let columns = [];
  let rows = [];
  // Assuming all the sections are correct
  let sections = true;

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {
    columns.push(getColumn(puzzle, i));
    rows.push(getRow(puzzle, i));
  }
  // Cycling through each section until one is not valid
  for (let i = 0; i < 3 && sections; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3 && sections; j++) {
      if (!sectionIncludes1To9(getSection(puzzle, i, j))) {
        sections = false;
      }
    }
  }
  // Returning true if columns, rows and sections are valid; false otherwise
  return arrayIncludes1To9(columns) && arrayIncludes1To9(rows) && sections;
}



let puzzleTwo = [[ 8,9,5,  7,4,2,  1,3,6 ],
                 [ 8,7,1,  9,6,3,  4,8,5 ],
                 [ 4,6,3,  5,8,1,  7,9,2 ],

                 [ 9,3,4,  6,1,7,  2,5,8 ],
                 [ 5,1,7,  2,3,8,  9,6,4 ],
                 [ 6,8,2,  4,5,9,  3,7,1 ],

                 [ 1,5,9,  8,7,4,  6,2,3 ],
                 [ 7,4,6,  3,2,5,  8,1,9 ],
                 [ 3,2,8,  1,9,6,  5,4,7 ]];

console.log(sudokuIsValid(puzzleTwo)); // false


i didnt think about adding another functions to store the section's values into, but and sorry for the question what is the element.map part? i dont see element anywhere unless im just over looking it

@RipperReborn I added comments to better explain the code, but to answer you keep in mind that matr is an array of array so, I cycle through each array inside matr and for each element I push them into a simple array declared before. This is just to reuse arrayIncludes1To9() and not doing another check, since that one is good enough
